# Ethernet not working (neither even detected) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ethernet

Ethernet is not being detected on my computer running Ubuntu 12.04 with LAMP. The last thing I remember doing is following this tutorial:
http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu

Here is the checks that I have performed. Hope it could help. Thanks!

```
vest@vest-blue-server:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:16736 (16.7 KB)  TX bytes:16736 (16.7 KB)

vest@vest-blue-server:~$ clear

vest@vest-blue-server:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:07.0 Bridge [0680]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet [10de:03ef] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4N68T series motherboard [1043:83a4]
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth
vest@vest-blue-server:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5b:39:eb:72:8e  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:23 Base address:0xe000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17680 (17.6 KB)  TX bytes:17680 (17.6 KB)

vest@vest-blue-server:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet ghcp
vest@vest-blue-server:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
vest@vest-blue-server:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224066  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
nouveau               774641  3 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ttm                    76949  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 nouveau
serio_raw              13211  0 
drm                   242038  5 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
k8temp                 13057  0 
edac_core              53746  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 nouveau
mxm_wmi                12979  1 nouveau
wmi                    19256  1 mxm_wmi
edac_mce_amd           23709  0 
snd                    78855  15 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
video                  19596  1 nouveau
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180104  7 bnep
parport_pc             32866  1 
ppdev                  17113  0 
asus_atk0110           18078  0 
i2c_nforce2            13058  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
sata_nv                32286  2 
forcedeth              63460  0 
pata_amd               14118  0 
vest@vest-blue-server:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x10de:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0 (forcedeth)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="48:5b:39:eb:72:8e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: Are you saying it used to work but after following that tutorial it stopped working?

Comment: But good job on including lots of relevant information. The quality of this question is a lot better than the vast majority of networking questions. +1

Comment: So far I remember it worked before it. But in order to solve the problem I might have messed a few things up so I included those details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your `/etc/network/interfaces` file which currently reads:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet ghcp
```

`ghcp` is not a thing. Change that file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**Edit:** If this is a desktop with Network Manager (per the standard loadout) you don't need a descriptor for `eth0` at all. It might even clash with `nm` so I'd suggest stripping `/etc/network/interfaces` back to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then give it a reboot and try again.

Comment: Thank you! I did that, and now network icon is showing up, but still it is not connecting. I have checked the cables properly.

Comment: @chetan Didn't realise this was a desktop - added another section.

Answer (score 0):

change the mac address in wired connection as 12 digits like 12:12:12:12:12:12, the restart your system, again change MAC address to default address then restart, your Ethernet will works good.

Comment: Could you include more information to indicate why/how your suggestion will be fixing the OP's issue?