# Connecting to the internet from the public library desktop computers

Tags: 12.04, wired

I have a live version of ubuntu 12.04 running flawlessly with persistance on my Kingston USB stick.

I wish to be able to log onto my public library's internet with this Ubuntu. However it doesn't connect on startup, as it does automatically in every other wired connection where I run t.

These computers have windows NT I believe installed by default, and it is extremely limited to the user. I can't access internet settings nor anything of that sort in order to see how does this internet connection works.

Clerks have no idea, they only switch on and off the cafe management software.

how to proceed?

Comment: See the question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277119/ethernet-not-working-neither-even-detected-on-ubuntu-12-04  and open a terminal and copy the commands one at a time: `ifconfig` `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` `ifconfig -a` `cat /etc/network/interfaces` `cat /etc/resolv.conf` etc. Then copy and paste the output as the original poster has done in your own question.

Comment: Suggest you gently chat up the clerks and ask them for a contact in Library IT so you can ask the IT folks if they have done so. There may be a proxy server between you and the internet you have to configure for.